# Stacking Android Widgets

Tags: android, widget

Is there any way a widget can be programmed to be stacked on another one? I'm trying to create a widget that would display an image, and then let the user add other widgets on top of the image.

I know that widgets can't be stacked on top of each other, but I'm wondering if there's a way to *create* a widget with this functionality.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: I guess a word better than stack would be "house". I want a widget to be embedded into another widget.

Comment: What about [StackView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/StackView.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Put your widgets inside a `FrameLayout` and add new items to it programmatically. Each child in `FrameLayout` is on top of the prevoius one, that one is on top on of previous one, ...